# Figure size in matplotlib is not changing

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, figsize

I want my graph to have equal scale in x and y axis when I zoom in with the navigation tools, but also bigger at the same time.

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlim([-20,20])
ax.set_ylim([-20,20])
ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box', anchor='C')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

However, even when I added

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (15,15)
```

or

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
```

[the size of the figure still stays the same.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuYPa.png)

I have also tried removing the

```
ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box', anchor='C')
```

[but then when I zoom in, the scale is inproportional](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzvMl.png)

I have tried removing

```
ax.set_xlim([-20,20])
ax.set_ylim([-20,20])
```

[but then it just doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EPSP.png)

Edit:
My program is a graphing calculator that generates graph from a user input

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

print("y = Ax^(4) + Bx^(3) + Cx^(2) + Dx + E")
list1 = [] 
for i in range(5):
    letter = chr(65+i)
    msg = letter + " = "
    userInput = input(msg)
    userInput = int(userInput)
    list1.append(userInput) #saving user input
x = np.linspace(-100, 100, 100000)
function = int(list1[0]) * x**4 + int(list1[1]) * x**3 + int(list1[2]) * x**2 + int(list1[3]) * x + int(list1[4])

plt.plot(x, function)
```

I tried calling `plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))` before `ax = plt.gca()` or call `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))` but then two graphs are generated in 2 separated windows.

I believe my question is not a duplicate because I have searched the same question in the site and I can't find one that mentions both scaling and size. I have also tried all solutions mentioned in the questions resolving figure size, but they didn't work for me

Comment: could you post a minimal reproducible problem? with the imports, the data, the plot instruction and the rest of the code. The code you posted cannot be ran because is missing parts.

Comment: Did you try calling `plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))` before `ax = plt.gca()`? Or, better yet, call `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))`?